# Is it possible to control dynamic bevel segments with a stylus?

Tags: bevel

I am learning to use Blender with a stylus and pen display. There are times when the mouse scroll wheel is used to do things like increasing or decreasing bevel segments dynamically. Is there any way to configure Blender, or some keyboard shortcuts that will do this when using a stylus?

Answer (score 2):

Found it. For Blender 2.79 the Numpad Minus and Numpad Plus also do what the missing scroll wheel does.

For Blender 2.8, When you are in the Bevel tool, press S (for Segments). At the bottom of the screen there is a list of all Bevel Properties that can be triggered with hotkeys. You can switch to different properties at will and the last setting will be set for you.